# Backbone sends form through GET

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js

I'm learning about Backbone.js and I built an app which has a form. 
Following the rules, I have a Book model, a Library collection, and a Book view. This view controls the form.

Everything runs ok, the communication with the API (which is running on Node.js) is also ok. But when I submit the form to save a new book, Backbone sends it through GET, and my API is waiting a POST (as it is used by CRUD operations).

The form submission is done by Backbone; when I click on submit, the called action is `this.collection.create( new BookModel(formData) )`. As we can see on Backbone's documentation, this action sends the model to the server, and after that the model is added to the collection.

Backbone.sync says that it sends the data through POST, but it is sending through GET.

I'm following the example of Developing Backbone.js Applications book.

Comment: show the value in formData

Comment: I found the problem.

I set the `el` as a `tbody` (I would like to have all the books listed in a table). If I set the `el` to `body` it works.

I'll have to set a View to the form, and another one to the list (table), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I set the view's `el` as `tbody` (I would like to have all the books listed inside a table).

If I set the `el` to `body` it works. It seems that we have to set a exclusive View to the form, and another one to the list (table).